# firebase: Strange behavious when modifying data: duplicates

Tags: typescript, firebase

Using firebase and ionic (typescript).

When adding a new entry (using push) into a collection (groups) it display a lot of temporary groups. I subscribed to them with the `on()` method and publish an event when data is changed. So everytime I add data inside the database, changes are immediate in the client without any interaction.

A few screenshot should explain far better what is happening:

**before adding:**
[image: before adding]

**After adding one group** (test_2) (directly after a `navctrl.pop()`):
[image: adding a group]

**After forcing the refresh of the list or if I load a group chat and exit**:
[image: refresh]

**If I delete 'test_2' directly inside firebase:**
[image: delete_wtf]

None of those 'duplicates' are present inside the database, only the client.
After adding, all the duplicates are 'valid' but not after deleting (since it was deleted from firebase). This only happen when adding data or deleting, not when initializing.

How can I prevent this ?

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thing is, the problem was only partly coming from my code :/ Only the rogue goups after deleting were an error (I wasn't clearing a variable correctly). The duplicates however were coming from firebase on() method which was called multiple time at the same time and adding and bypassing the reset of the variable.

I'm new to firebase and I didn't find this problem earlier when I asked my question leading to this mess :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that with firebase (is it a bug ?) I need to turn off the `on()` method before using it. Not doing so were triggering the `on()` method and my `subscribe()` multiple time, bypassing my reset of the variable, leading to duplicates.

I added a `off()` method before the `on()` and it solved my problem.

```
this.fireuser.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child('groups/').off();
this.fireuser.child(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).child('groups/').on('value', (snapshot) => {...})
```